# Express on Node - what data store?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, redis, express

I'm doing my first project in node/express.

I'm looking to implement a data store and noticed that express is using redis as a session store. Does this mean that express installs redis by default? The reason I ask is that I pondering whether to install mongodb but if redis is already there to use, I'll go with that.

New to node and express so any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I checked, express used a built-in in-memory data store by default and connect-redis was a separate package.

express installs neither redis (the database executable) nor node-redis (redis API binding for node) nor connect-redis (session store for connect and express that uses redis).

redis is a very simple database compared to mongodb. Mongodb is a full document-oriented database and redis is just an in-memory key-value store.

Also, express relies on connect for most stuff including session management, and sessions are in fact provided by connect.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason I ask is that I pondering whether to install mongodb but if
>   redis is already there to use, I'll go with that.

Question you should rather ask is if redis would be the right data store for your stuff. Redis doesn't support for example querying which might be crucial for you and your data retrieval, so if that's one of your requirements you should go with mongodb.

Comment: Good point : I just need somewhere to throw some key value pairs for now. - thanks.